# Laravel Exception not being thrown outside controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im wondering if someone could help me out. I have a class which is testing for an ftp connection. when i run the code inside my controller it works perfectly, but when i put the code inside its own class, it fails to throw anything. my code is as follows

```
use Exception;

class Backup implements BackupContract
{

    public function testConnection($credentials)
    {
        try {
            $connection = @ftp_connect($credentials['host']);
            if (false === $connection) {
                throw new Exception('Cant connect.');
            }

            $logged_in = @ftp_login($connection, $credentials['username'], $credentials['password']);
            if (false === $logged_in) {
                throw new Exception('Credentials wrong.');
            }
            @ftp_close($connection);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->route('createbackup')->withInput()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because the exception was catch by `} catch (\Exception $e) {` and inside that block you redirected the page.

Comment: @vher2 Im not sure what you mean ... The same code works correctly inside a standard controller

Comment: In your standard controller you also have that `redirect()->route( ....`?

Comment: The code is the same, in the controller it works, outside the controller it doesn

Comment: what is the value of `$connection` and `$logged_in`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are either going to need to namespace the class:

`namespace App\Classes`

or remove the `use Exception` and use:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
   return redirect()
   ->route('createbackup')
   ->withInput()
   ->withErrors($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It is namespaced namespace App\Procedures\Backup;

Comment: OK, is the Exception actually being thrown?  i.e. is it actually going inside the `if` blocks to throw the exception, if so is it going inside the `catch` block?